# Accessing variables in protocol methods in swift

Tags: swift

can anyone please help me with this swift code, i'm a swift beginner.
i'm trying to create a login page using MVC and it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhAtk.png)

so when the user enters their login information and the status from the JSON data is "s" for a successful login it should display some test information, and when the login status is "f" for a failed login it should stay in the same login page, i'm trying to access the status in the protocol method in the code below:

so whenever the user presses the button it should take the required action but the status in the code below is nil so whenever i run the application the information is displayed wether the login was successful or not

```
//this piece of code is in the LoginViewController
        func didReceivedLoginInfo(info : [LoginModel]) -> String
            {
                self.loginData = info
                print("didReceivedLOOGIN count is \(loginData!.count)")//the print is successful here
                for i in 0..<loginData!.count
                {
                    print("LoginData Info : \(loginData![i])")//the print is successful here
                }
                statuss = loginData![0].status
                print("HERE YOU GO, THIS IS WHAT I FOUND: \(statuss!)")//the print is successful here
               return statuss! 
            }

//this piece of code is in the LoginViewController
    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
        {
            var btnsendtag: UIButton = sender
                var uName  = username!.text as? String!
                var uPass  = password!.text as? String!
                parser = LoginParser()
                parser!.getLoginInfo(uName!, pass: uPass!)
                var status = loginData?[0].status
                print("from View Controller this is the msg: \(status)")
                parser!.delegate = self
                if status == "s"            {
                    print("from View Controller this is the status: \(status)")
                    let vc = ViewController()
                    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                else {
                    let vc = LoginViewController()
                    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                           }
        }



     ////this piece of code is in the LoginParser
        import UIKit

        @objc protocol LoginParserDelegate : NSObjectProtocol

        {

            func didReceivedLoginInfo (info : [LoginModel]) -> String

            optional func didRecivedError()

        }



        class LoginParser: NSObject {

            // var  webData: NSMutableData?

            var webData: NSData?
            weak var delegate : LoginParserDelegate?
            var name = String ()
            var model : LoginModel?
            var alertView:UIAlertView?
            var MainLogin : [LoginModel] = []

            func getLoginInfo (usern : String, pass : String){

                var post:NSString = "LID=\(usern)&PWD=\(pass)&Passcode=s@v#"
                var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "some link")!
                var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

                var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

                request.HTTPBody = postData

                request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

                request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

                var response: NSURLResponse?

                let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
            }


            func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError){

                if delegate != nil {
                    if delegate!.respondsToSelector(Selector("didRecivedLoginInfo")){
                        delegate!.didRecivedError!()
                    }

                }
            }

            func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse){

                webData = NSData()


            }

            func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData){

                webData! = data
            }

            func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection){
                let responseString = NSString(data: webData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString \(responseString!)")

                processUserTypes ()

            }

            func processUserTypes ()->[LoginModel]
            {
                model = LoginModel()

                // Process JSON

                do {
                    let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(webData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)as? NSDictionary


                    var Login = LoginModel()


                    let status = result?.objectForKey("Status") as? String
                    let msg = result?.objectForKey("En") as? String
                    let employeename=result?.objectForKey("DisplayName")as? String
                    print("STATUS IN PARSER IS \(status!)")

                    if status == "s"

                    {

                        print(status!)
                        Login.name = employeename
                        Login.status = status
                        Login.message = msg
                        alertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView!.title = "Login successful"
                        alertView!.message = "Welcome \(employeename!)"
                        alertView!.delegate = self
                        alertView!.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView!.show()
                        MainLogin.append(Login)
                        print("count in login is  \(MainLogin.count)")
                        if delegate != nil
                        {
                            delegate!.didReceivedLoginInfo(MainLogin)
                        }

                    }

                    else

                    {
                        Login.message = msg
                        alertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView!.title = "Login failed"
                        alertView!.message = msg!
                        alertView!.delegate = self
                        alertView!.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView!.show()

                        MainLogin.append(Login)
                        print("this is the main login\(MainLogin)")


                    }

                           }
                catch {

                    if delegate != nil {
                        if delegate!.respondsToSelector(Selector("didRecivedLoginInfo")){
                            delegate!.didRecivedError!()
                        }


                    }



                }
                return MainLogin
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me with this?
thanks

Comment: what does getLoginInfo do? who calls didReceivedLoginInfo? the the view controller the parsers delegate? if so you set it too late

Comment: didReceivedLoginInfo is called in the LoginViewController, this method is a protocol method in the LoginParser

Comment: yes but how does the code of the parser look like. and why do you first call methods on the parser and then set the delegate

Comment: This is the protocol in the LoginInfo:                                                                       @objc protocol LoginParserDelegate : NSObjectProtocol
    
{
    
    func didReceivedLoginInfo (info : [LoginModel]) -> String
    
    optional func didRecivedError()
    
}

Comment: no i mean when does it call the delegate? inside getLoginInfo? and is getLoginInfo a sync method or does it async work?

Comment: i'll try to post the parser code now

Comment: this is a async issue. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you call `didReceivedLoginInfo`inside `processUserTypes`which is called inside `connectionDidFinishLoading`. `buttonAction` calls `getLoginInfo`which does an async request that will call back `connectionDidFinishLoading` when it is done.

this `getLoginInfo`will return a long time before the request is send out and a respone is received and `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called.

=> you cannot do anything after you call getLogininfo

=>

for you button method

1. create the parser
2. set the delegate
3. call getLoginInfo
4. dont do anything with potential results here

for the didReceiveLoginInfo.

you can do further logic and maybe even ui stuff there (you have to wrap logic that affects the ui in a

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
     //here
}
```

call

Comment: i tried to do that but this time the application doesn't take the user to the test information page when the login is successful

Comment: Did you debug the. Code

Comment: yes, the status variable inside the button function is still nil

Comment: As I said. if you debug the delegate method and the button method you will see that the delegate method will not be called when you try to access the variable

Comment: Thanks a lot i will keep on trying

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you i really really appreciate your very great help